# Powering electromagnets with a piezoelectric charge

Tags: electromagnetism

Could you power an electromagnet with the charge from a piezoelectric crystal like quartz and if you could would it be able to generate a strong magnetic field

Comment: Yes, but why would you? It's much easier and more efficient to generate electricity using magnetic fields, which is what we usually do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you could but you would probably want to save the amperage and voltage generated in a capacitor or battery and then use it after a build up and then run an electromagnet. The strength of the magnetic field would be dependent on the amount of Power you ultimately store up in the capacitor or battery.

How it works -
In most crystals (such as metals), the unit cell (the basic repeating unit) is symmetrical; in piezoelectric crystals, it isn't. Normally, piezoelectric crystals are electrically neutral: the atoms inside them may not be symmetrically arranged, but their electrical charges are perfectly balanced: a positive charge in one place cancels out a negative charge nearby. However, if you squeeze or stretch a piezoelectric crystal, you deform the structure, pushing some of the atoms closer together or further apart, upsetting the balance of positive and negative, and causing net electrical charges to appear. This effect carries through the whole structure so net positive and negative charges appear on opposite, outer faces of the crystal.

The reverse-piezoelectric effect occurs in the opposite way. Put a voltage across a piezoelectric crystal and you're subjecting the atoms inside it to "electrical pressure." They have to move to rebalance themselves—and that's what causes piezoelectric crystals to deform (slightly change shape) when you put a voltage across them.

So put enough crystals together in a system and stress them mechanically and you can generate quite a lot of electric current for storage. Imagine a road surface made up of pizeoelectric crystals and run thousands trucks across the road for a day. One could imagine quite alot of Power being generated from this.